# NET Core supporting on Apache Kafka and Confluent Cloud

Tags: apache-kafka

I’m sorry for my question, I’m newbie in Apache Kafka. I simple need for my .NET CORE program Confluent.Kafka classes https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-dotnet/_site/api/Confluent.Kafka.html

If I understand even simple Apache KAFKA can support this classes (with NET client) - yes or no? But in this page Comparing Features & Capabilities Apache Kafka and Confluent (section Unrestricted Developer Productivity) https://www.confluent.io/apache-kafka-vs-confluent/?_ga=2.196997167.245483310.1688728107-249351602.1688629318 I see that ONLY Confluent support .NET CORE. This is little bit confused me.

I have installed on my server both of them - Apache Kafka and Confluent Cloud (from this instruction https://docs.confluent.io/platform/7.4/installation/overview.html ), both of them successfully worked except one - Confluent cloud absolutely opened to anybody from https://MyServer:9021 without any username and password. Even to continue various experiments and compare future of them I need firstly setup username and password, but unfortunately I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confluent Platform includes Apache Kafka.

Confluent publishes a .NET Kafka client that will work with any Kafka cluster. Only Confluent developers "*support* (development of)" the .NET Client.

HTTP Port 9021 is *Confluent Control Center*; unrelated to .NET clients or Confluent Cloud.

Comment: Thank you. but please clarify little bit. Your answer mean that clear Apache Kafka without full Confluent Cloud can not support classes for my .NET CORE program, isn't it? So, that mean simple Apache Kafka can not useful for my .NET program, isn't it? But I don't understand license policy of Confluent company. I see something parameters named LICENSE in config, but in reality - is this free, or not free for payment.

Comment: And please one more clarification. Yes, you are right, this is control center, I need something GUI tools for control how messages processing. Currently I found only one solution to close access to unauthorized user - by UFW. But maybe there is solution with Login/Password to Confluent Control center, I can not found how to do that.

Comment: As answered, .NET client works with any Kafka cluster. It is Apache 2.0 licensed, so free. The server really does not care about client-side classes/libraries. Control Center doesn't prevent Kafka access. No UI tool will do that